# How to create a runtime variable-size array efficiently in C++?

Tags: c++, dynamic-memory-allocation, dynamic-arrays

Our library has a lot of chained functions that are called thousands of times when solving an engineering problem on a mesh every time step during a simulation.  In these functions, we must create arrays whose sizes are only known at runtime, depending on the application.  There are three choices we have tried so far, as shown below:

```cpp
void compute_something( const int& n )
{
    double fields1[n];               // Option 1.
    auto *fields2 = new double[n];   // Option 2.
    std::vector<double> fields3(n);  // Option 3.

    // .... a lot more operations on the field variables ....
}
```

From these choices, *Option 1* has worked with our current compiler, but we know it's not safe because we may overflow the stack (plus, it's non standard).  *Option 2* and *Option 3* are, on the other hand, safer, but using them as frequently as we do, is impacting the performance in our applications to the point that the code runs ~6 times slower than using *Option 1*.

What are other options to handle memory allocation efficiently for dynamic-sized arrays in C++?  We have considered constraining the parameter `n`, so that we can provide the compiler with an upper bound on the array size (and optimization would follow); however, in some functions, `n` can be pretty much arbitrary and it's hard to come up with a precise upper bound.  Is there a way to circumvent the overhead in dynamic memory allocation?  Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Choose a language — C or C++, not both.  The answers are quite different, depending on which you choose!  The code is C++, not C, so presumably the C tag should go.

Comment: I have set the question for C++.  We are flexible, though :).  If C offers a better approach, we'll go for it.

Comment: There are three viable options. 1. `std::vector`. 2. `std::vector`. 3. `std::vector`.

Comment: Option 1 is valid in C (C99 mandatory; C11, C18 optional; C23 requires support for VLAs, but doesn't require support for automatic storage of VLAs).  It does run a risk of overflowing the stack — you'd have to be careful about stack depth.

Comment: One thing you *do not* want is fixed-length C arrays, and you doubly do not want `new[]` and all the agony that comes with managing that memory properly. Remember, `std::vector` is not slow. It's the backbone of pretty much any high-performance C++ code, and is used *everywhere*. Remember with vectors if you know, roughly, how big they're going to end up when you're done populating them you can always `reserve` that in advance to minimize allocation calls.

Comment: One way to reduce the cost of dynamic memory allocation is to do less of it.  Can you allocate more carefully — and reuse rather than release?  That might be easier in C than in C++.

Comment: Option 1 is not valid in standard C++.  Option 2 is valid, but highly error prone (potential leaks, etc).   Option 3 is valid, and mitigates several errors associated with Option 2.   If performance matters, focus on algorithms - and minimise how *often* a dynamically allocated array is allocated/deallocated (i.e. take care with changing size and capacity of a vector).

Comment: Is freeing memory necessary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create a cache at startup and pre-allocate with a reasonable size.
2. Pass the cache to your compute function or make it part of your class if `compute()` is a method
3. Resize the cache

```
std::vector<double> fields;
fields.reserve( reasonable_size );
...
void compute( int n, std::vector<double>& fields ) {       
     fields.resize(n);
     // .... a lot more operations on the field variables ....
}
```

This has a few benefits.

1. First, most of the time the size of the vector will be changed but no allocation will take place due to the exponential nature of std::vector's memory management.
2. Second, you will be reusing the same memory so it will be likely it will stay in cache.